# Is it possible to set the DNS and Gateway but still use dhcp to set ip address in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server?

Tags: 18.04, server, netplan

I use a ubuntu 18.04 LTS server, and I find the content of the yaml file in /etc/netplan is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
```

I want to set the dns server and gateway to my config,but still set the ip address using the dhcp, so is it possible to set the netplan as follow?

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 9.9.9.9
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With netplan.io version 0.98 which is in bionic-updates, you can do this using the `dhcp4-overrides` section:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
        use-routes: false
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 9.9.9.9
```

Comment: Wonderful, excatly what I'm seeking.